# Adding 2nd Y Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to add an additional y axis to the right of my diagram.

As described in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/), I added an additional value axis and positioned it on the right:

```
{
  "id": "v2",
  "position": "right"
}
```

But it seems to just be ignored.

This is my entire code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("mydia", {
  "type": "xy",
  "dataProvider": data,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "position": "left"
  }, {
    "id": "v2",
    "position": "right"
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]",
    "xField": "ax",
    "yField": "ay",
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]",
    "xField": "bx",
    "yField": "by",
  }],
});
```

Anybody an idea?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oevgszq7/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign a graph to the second Y Axis or else they'll all use the first valueAxis. This is done through the [`yAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#yAxis) property in the XY chart:

```
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "xField": "ax",
    "yField": "ay"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]",
    "yAxis": "v2", //needs to be the ID or valueAxis object itself
    "bullet": "round",
    "xField": "bx",
    "yField": "by"
  }],
```

Note that you also need to have data in the graph that uses the second yAxis or it will not appear at all.

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oevgszq7/2/) with some dummy data for the second graph.